# VS2010 Keyboard Shortcut - Show ToolTip

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Question:  How to display the mouse hover over tooltip in VS2010 using a keyboard shortcut?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> gives some detail on overloads.

Cheers

Dave

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The mouse hover info is called "Quick Info".  The default keybinding for it in the C# profile is <kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd>.

It's also the third icon from the left in the "Text Editor" toolbar: [image: quick info icon].

Answer (score 6):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut shows the *exact* same information as the tooltip (i.e. the member summary and the first overload).  Is there a particular reason that you need to see the tooltip specifically?

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. in the code example above when hovering over ActionResult, and pressing Ctrl Shift Space.. nothing happens.  However Ctrl-k, Ctrl-i does.

Comment: @DaveMateer this is the same with me, ctrl+shift+space is not working for me. only ctrl shift space. I'm needing to use old VS 2010 to do the Xbox live indie game tutorials which are not compatible with later versions of VS 2012 or 2013 as far as I can work out...